# Can I do good math research if I am mediocre in graduate course?

Tags: self-learning, learning

I mostly got B's in my graduate courses like algebraic topology, differential geometry, algebraic geometry and etc, and I start to lose confidence and patience because of this. Is it still possible to become a good mathematics researcher (in graph theory) with such a mediocre grade?

Comment: This is really an opinionated question, so probably doesn't belong in this website. In my personal opinion, a $B$ is actually a good grade. Even still - grades can be very misleading since there is a lot of context they simply don't take into account. No one on this website will know your situation enough to give you any definite answers, even people that do know you personally won't be able to give you any definite answers. I would simply say that there are going to be lots of times in Mathematics you get frustrated when you don't understand something, but that doesn't mean you should give up

Comment: In fact - Mathematics would be really boring if everything was easy and answers were just copy and pasted. To me, the struggle is what makes it fun and interesting. When you go through the struggle and eventually understand something, it's very thrilling

Comment: I'm not sure this is an on-topic question, though it certainly is interesting. But as a graduate student myself, I certainly hope so! One of the most talented students in my class (much more so than myself) had a mediocore grade in real analysis. Grades aren't everything, IMO you should focus on becoming an expert on one subject and solving a couple reasonable open problems and you'll be fine.

Comment: If God helps you, you could become a great Mathematician. this is my point of view.

Comment: @NN2: that is one of the most dismal things that I have ever read. And a great advertisement for uncreative complacency.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose , that's the point. After getting these B's , i start to lose passion to mathematics, where  I found I hate to struggle with the problems, but I am not sure it is just temporary frustration or it is a feeling that had been with me for a long time. I was thinking to change field to biostatistics but I am worried the gap is huge.

Comment: @kaoTanA I also don't know anything about biostatistics, so I cannot say of how big the gap is. Whether you continue to study Mathematics entirely depends on you and what is important to you. I think a lot of people start to lose faith in themselves and thus lose their passion usually when they feel they are struggling more than other people they see, and so begin to think "*I'm not good enough at Mathematics to continue studying it, I'm not wired that way*". The thing is - no matter who you are, there is always someone out their who knows just *that bit more* than you, but this is totally ok

Comment: @kaoTanA Sometimes people also just have burnout, and need a break from Mathematics. This is also okay. In every profession, regular breaks are standard, and I see no reason why Mathematics would be any different. To summarise: it's okay to struggle (it's part of the process), and it's okay to take breaks. If you love Mathematics, let that be your reason for studying it. If you find you no longer love it - switching profession is okay. Of course this is all just my personal thoughts, you need to think about all of this yourself and **make your own decision**. No one can do that for you